# Laravel oauth user redirection after registration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, single-sign-on

all. I'm just trying to implement Single sign-on server using Laravel and passport app.

**What I'm trying to achieve:** A single sign-on server who listen to the request from the client and provide the authentication based on the requested parameter.

**What I've achieved so far:** The SSO server who listen to the client request and provide the authentication and redirect back to the client site only if the user already registered on the SSO server.

The problem is coming to the picture when the user is not registered on SSO server and try to register the account In this case Laravel register user and redirect back to the homepage instead client callback URL.
Please let me know if this is achievable in Laravel or someone does something special for it.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty much achievable, depends on how much effort you want to put towards it.

When the user is registering, you can save the callback URL in the session.

```
session(['callback' => $callback]);
```

Upon registration, redirect the user to their callback URL

```
return redirect()->away(session('callback'));
```

If you are still using the default Auth/RegisterController provided by laravel, you can change the redirect behavior by defining a custom redirect function

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return redirect()->away(session('callback'));
}
```

Laravel will automatically pick it up.

Don't forget to delete the property

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is what I don't require. What I need is to redirect the user to client server with authentication key generated by laravel passport app. Which works fine if the user logged in using existing credentials however not in the registration.

Comment: You could add the token to the callback... but yeah. Not exactly what you wanted. Sorry.

Comment: Yes I have checked with it and  changed the workflow. Anyway thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with some customization in default registration functionality, you have to replace some code in RegistrationController as provided below:

**app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegistrationController**

> use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

```
use AuthenticatesUsers, RegistersUsers {
    AuthenticatesUsers::redirectPath insteadof RegistersUsers;
    AuthenticatesUsers::guard insteadof RegistersUsers;
}

public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));


    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        if ($request->hasSession()) {
            $request->session()->put('auth.password_confirmed_at', time());
        }
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }
}
```